# How to change "Person or Group" autocomplete field to dropdown list

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, groups, person

I am looking for a way to change the autocomplete field of "Person or Group" to a dropdown list.

I checked the Lookup field solution, that doesn't suit me, i only need to transform the autocomplete to a dropdown list.

From this : [image]

To this :

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this OOTB. But as an alternative you can edit the form using PowerApps (requires permissions). Initially the form looks like below:
[image]

Now, edit the form using Customize with PowerApps button. The PowerApps screen will open. Follow the below steps (steps are mapped to the image below):
[image]

1. Remove the existing drop-down (combo-box) of your people picker field and click on insert and add a drop-down from there.
2. SharePoint Online people pickers show users from the Office Users (Azure AD). There is a data source provided by PowerApps to get all the users in the Azure AD called - `Office365Users`
3. Now click on the newly added drop-down and select "Items" from top dropdown besides formula. Enter the below formula in the formula bar.

   Office365Users.SearchUser({top:100})

Here, top:100 means the top 100 users will be shown. You can check adding different numbers according to your requirement. For the same dropdown, click on properties (right side), we already filled the "Items", now "Value" is to be selected (field of the user to be displayed in the dropdown as options). Select the value you want to show in your dropdown. For your requirement it should be - `DisplayName`

Once this is done and all errors are gone. Save the powerapps and go back to your SharePoint list. The people picker will be a dropdown as shown below.
[image]

This is just a workaround if you have access to PowerApps in your subscription.

Comment: very well, i understand. I already did this solution and yes i have access to PowerApps, but when i share the site with an external guest (while this site contain some customised forms with PowerApps), it required from them to buy or to have a plan that have access to PowerApps.

Comment: Does it give them option for trial account?

Comment: Absolutely not, The form won't even appear for those external users

Answer (score 0):

OOTB doesn't have that feature. To have a dropdown, try to customize the form using PowerApps.

Answer (score 0):

That is no OOB settings to control the behavior for that column. You can customize it in a InfoPath/PowerApps forms

Answer (score 0):

I created a modern test team site and added a Person/group column in the list. By default the results are coming in the dropdown. Do you need something else? [image]

Comment: you typed "ada" then the result appears to you, what i'm looking for is how to click in the arrow of the DropDown list then all the persons will appear to you without typing any letter.

Comment: Okay. Then PowerApps is the only way to do it.